# Capturing enter key for WxPython Styled Text Control

Tags: python, wxpython, scintilla

Using a StyledTextControl in wxpython by importing `wx.stc`, how can i capture the Enter Key as an event? i've tried several methods but all seem to be saying errors or not working at all.

so fair ive got:

```
self.text.Bind(wx.stc.STC_KEY_DOWN, self.hw)

def hw(self, event):
  if event.GetKeyCode == wx.stc.STC_KEY_RETURN:
    self.text.AddText('Hello World')
    event.Skip()
```

where `self.text` is my stc.

Just doesnt seem to be working for me. Do i use wx functions or stc functions for capturing the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should use StyledTextCtrl events for handling events in a StyledTextCtrl, not wx events.

The most obvious event to handle would seem to be `EVT_STC_KEY`.  However, according to the [documentation for the event](http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/events.html#EVT_STC_KEY), this might not work:

> The Scintilla documentation says:
>
> > `Reports all keys pressed. Used on GTK+ because of some problems with keyboard focus. Not sent by Windows version.`
>
> As far as this writer can tell, this means that this event, although technically available thru wxWindows, will not actually ever occur.

You can try handling the `EVT_STC_CHARADDED` event instead, but that seems to be called after a new line has been added.  Calling `event.Skip()` for this event has no effect.  On Windows, this event fires twice, once for the carriage-return `\r` and once for the newline `\n`.

Ultimately, it's possible that what you are trying to achieve might not be possible.

(Incidentally,  `STC_KEY_DOWN` is a code that represents the down-arrow key, not that a key has been pressed down.)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN`, and Return key is 13

Answer (score 1):

Hi I know this is a little old now but I used this and it seems to work.

```
import wx
import wx.stc

self.m_message = TextCtrl( self, ID_ANY, EmptyString, DefaultPosition, Size( 200,100 ), 0 )
self.m_message.Bind(EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.DoKeyPress)

def DoKeyPress(self, event):
    if event.GetKeyCode() == STC_KEY_RETURN:
        self.DoSendTextMessage(event)
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

Comment: This does not work for me, you have to write wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN and wx.stc.STC_KEY_RETURN for this code to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually explained in the documentation: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html. Setting the style to TE_PROCESS_ENTER will enable the event and then you can just bind it.

```
from wx import TextCtrl, EVT_TEXT_ENTER, TE_PROCESS_ENTER
text_input = TextCtrl(parent, style=TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
text_input.Bind(EVT_TEXT_ENTER, callback)
```